# After I have started/start something

Tags: present-perfect, syntax

'Present perfect' or 'simple present': Which one should I use in the following context?

After I have started/start earning, I have realized how much money I have wasted demanding silly things from parents.

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect in your main clause, *I have realized ...*, marks this a statement about the present: you know **now** how much money you wasted.

Consequently it requires that the moment or timespan designated by any temporal modifier include the present.

*After* will not work in this context. Although the time *after* some past time—let's call it *after [past X]*—may in mere logic include the present, it does not **require** a present interpretation. In practice, *after [past X]* is only used to locate events which occurred after X but before the present.

> After I started earning I ***realized*** how much I had wasted.

What you want in this situation is *since*, which designates the timespan running from *[past X]* up to the present; and *[past X]*, since it is a specific past event, should be cast in the simple past:

> Since I **started** earning I have realized how much I have wasted.

You may wish to recast *have wasted* as simple past *wasted* if you want to indicate that you are no longer wasting money that way.

Comment: Can I write it as "after starting earning, I have realized how much I have wasted?"

Comment: @user250189 You can, but *since* is still better.